# API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API gateway for an API deployed in ec2 instance. I have already created role for it using IAM in AWS and added all the permissions as shown in the below. but while testing api i am getting this error  `API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role`.

Trust Entities

```py
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: How API could assume the role, as the role is for ec2 (`ec2.amazonaws.com`)?

Comment: @Marcin I didn't understand. So what should i have to change?

Comment: API gateway can only assume a role if it has `apigateway.amazonaws.com` for `Principal`.

Comment: Thanks adding it to Principal solved the problem

Comment: @Marcin The solution worked. But i am facing another problem. If you want to take a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677395/the-action-deploy-is-not-valid-for-this-web-service-while-calling-api-through-ap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

For the role to be assumable by an API gateway, `apigateway.amazonaws.com` principal needs to be used:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```