# The action deploy is not valid for this web service while calling api through api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am using API gateway to call the API in ec2 instance. When i tested the api i am getting the output below with status:200. But it should show "Success" message.why is it happening?. Do i need to change anything to get the proper output while doing get request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Errors><Error>
<Code>InvalidAction</Code>
<Message>The action deploy is not valid for this web service.</Message>
</Error></Errors>
<RequestID>4c2aeb89-1dfe-4a95-a9fd-7af28b49c708</RequestID>
</Response>
```

Steps I followed to create the API

1. created a restapi in api gateway as shown in figure
   [image]
2. After that i have added the api end points using resources and methods and connected to aws ec2 instance as shown in the figure
   [image]
3. I have created the execution role arn by going into IAM roles and added all the roles shown in the figure.
   [image]
   [image]
4. later if i test the api endpoint by providing the query parameters i am getting this error
   [image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details how did you setup your API, its integration with EC2, and what the EC2 is exactly doing or running?

Comment: on EC2 i have deployed docker container which is running fastapi. so i was trying to add api gateway to control the api calls and authentication. I have created a RestAPI in api gate way and connected to ec2 instance.

Comment: "connected to ec2" but how? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. The error msg says that you are using invalid action. What actions do you have? How did you define them? Only you know this, no one else on SO.

Comment: @Marcin i have provided all the information, how i created and connected to ec2 instance please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use API as proxy to your EC2 docker app. Its not "AWS Service". You must choose and [setup HTTP integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html) type. "AWS Service" would be used if your were creating API proxy to the actual EC2 service (e.g. launch an instance, stop an instance, ...).

Depending on the nature of you EC2 docker app, if you just setup plain HTTP (http://<defulat-ec2-url) this will be going over **unencrypted** (not HTTPS) connection. So be mindful of that. If your API contains sensitive info, this is a security issue.

Comment: Thanks i understood now. can we limit the API request call and add authentication to the HTTP integration? @Marcin

Comment: @daylightisminetocommand Yes, you can do same as for other integrations